# Color-picker showing color names

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, colors

Does anyone know of a `color-picker` for Visual Studio (Visual Basic) that shows the names of the standard colors?

For example, in Visual Studio, you can alter the color of a control using a `color-picker` that has tabs of `"Custom"`, `"Web"` and `"System"`.  The `Web` & `System` options show a list of the color names, whereas `Custom` supplies (mainly) RGB (which is what the VB ColorPicker control does).

Thanks!

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/it-IT/e21c8b6f-6750-46b1-86be-c69ecac9e7a5/colorpicker-combobox?forum=winforms

Comment: Hi, many thanks for input, most helpful.  Hans, thanks for the link - exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is precious little to one of these until you want to do like VS and present System Colors apart from Named Colors, make it a popup or some such.  Example using colors as the BackGround:

```
' capture the names
Private _Colors As String()

' get the names 
' add qualifiers to skip SystemCOlors or
' Transparent as needed
Function GetColorNames As String()
    For Each colorName As String In KnownColor.GetNames(GetType(KnownColor))
       _Colors.Add(colorName)
    End If
Next

' post the names to a CBO:
cboBackColor.Items.AddRange(_Colors)
```

On the form CBO, set the DrawMode to `OwnerDrawFixed`, then:

```
Private Sub cboSheetBackColor_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, 
           ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) 
           Handles cboSheetBackColor.DrawItem
    Dim Bclr As Color, Fclr As Color

    ' get the colors to use for this item for this
    Bclr = Color.FromName(_Colors(e.Index).ToString)
    Fclr = GetContrastingColor(Bclr)     ' see below

    With e.Graphics
        Using br As New SolidBrush(Bclr)
            .FillRectangle(br, e.Bounds)
        End Using
        Using br As New SolidBrush(Fclr)
            .DrawString(cboSheetBackColor.Items(e.Index).ToString,
             cboSheetBackColor.Font, br, 
             e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y)
        End Using

    End With
    e.DrawFocusRectangle()

End Sub
```

You **can** just draw a swatch like Windows/VS does by defining a rectangle to fill.  Generally, thats swell, but in the case where you are doing something like defining a background color it rather helps to show how it looks with text on it and more of the color than the little bitty swatch - hence the filled CBO Item rect.

The standard window Text color will not show up on all of them.  For a "light" theme, Violet and Black etc will hide/make the color name impossible to read. `GetContrastingColor` is a function which evaluates the Brightness of the current color and then returns either White or Black:

```
Public Function GetContrastingColor(ByVal clrBase As Color) As Color
    ' Y is the "brightness"
    Dim Y As Double = (0.299 * clrBase.R) _
            + (0.587 * clrBase.G) _
            + (0.114 * clrBase.B)

    If (Y < 140) Then
        Return Color.White
    Else
        Return Color.Black
    End If
End Function
```

You can then use all this in a Class which inherits from ComboBox, or build a UserControlif you like distinct controls.  You can also leave it as code in a DLL which is called on those occasions.  I should mention there are also perhaps a dozen such critters on CodeProject.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about an existing control but you can use the `KnownColor` enumeration and the `SystemColors` class to get all the names of those `Color` values.  You can then build your own control, e.g. custom `ComboBox`, with that data.