# Is it possible to have a collection with just colours in a combo box?

Tags: vb.net, collections, colors, combobox

Trying to make something in visual basic. One of the elements of this something is to have settings where you can set the various colours of buttons, labels and such. My idea is this, have a combo box where it drops down to show just colours, not words; like the effect of adding a backcolour to a label and taking out the words.

EDIT: Thank you for your help Fernando, but I've realized that my question was formed in a confusing manner, and your answer was not what I has asking.

http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/controls/creating-a-color-picker-with-an-owner-draw-combobox

I was trying to get something more like this, but without the words if possible (and yes I have tried the code there already, visual basic doesn't recognize ColorInfo)

Comment: Have you tried anything? Solution will come from setting the draw mode and then overriding the drawitem method I believe it's called, painting just a rectangle filled with your color, using a list of all colors as the data source

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23303330/1070452

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Here is an example:

```
Public Class Form1
Private colors As List(Of Color)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ColorDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Me.BackColor = ColorDialog1.Color
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' add as many colors as you want
    colors = New List(Of Color)
    colors.Add(Color.AliceBlue)
    colors.Add(Color.Beige)
    colors.Add(Color.Black)
    ' and so on

    For Each c In colors
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(c)
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Me.BackColor = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
End Sub
```

End Class

I also added an example with a colordialog control. You can insert it and get the color you want from it, it's implemented on the button_click event. Which i think is the best option.